# iOS - Disable "Take Photo or Video"

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I have created a Cordova app, but in-app browser, but the problem is with the "Take Photo or Video" feature.

If you want to upload an image from a camera device, the app crashes.

My idea is, how to disable that feature?

[image]

I don't want (If it is not necessary) to install camera device support from Cordova or the same... Thank you!

Comment: How do you get pictures? Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in info.plist file. This fix 'take photo', or problem with video will be stay

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

Comment: Probably also require turning on the microphone, otherwise it crashes with just the NSCameraUsageDescription, e.g.,  <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key><string>This app requires access to the microphone.</string>